# How to Change the Origin when moving a Collection Instance

Tags: origin, collections

I have created an **Collection Instance**, when I try to move it, the **origin**(to snap at vertices or edges) is **far away from the object**, I want to set it.

[image]

In the image, the Collection Instance is selected, the cross is far away from the object and **I can´t set it using "Set Origin to 3D Cursor"**

What Am I missing?

Comment: Not the best solution, but in edit mode of objects, the origin point doesn't move.  Can you try moving the collection group in edit mode?

Comment: If you Right Click the collection and "Select Objects" it should allow you to do it then. But I'm not sure if this would solve your issue.

Answer (score 24):

### First Method : Set the origin in the base collection

To change the origin of a collection instance, you have to go to the object information panel, then the collections foldout and choose "set offset from cursor" with the drop-down popup on the right of the collection name.

[image]

### Alternative method

Select the collection you want to use as an instance. Go to the collection properties (Collection icon in the properties editor) and change the X, Y, Z values.

[image]

[Link to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/collections.html)

Here you also have access to two other options in the dropdown menu, *Set Offset From Object*, and *Set Cursor to Offset*.

[image]

### Second Method : Set the origin in the collection instance

There is another way to do it as pointed out in the comments. Select the collection instance and type <kbd>F3</kbd> to search for "Set Origin" and choose accordingly to your case. Alternatively go to Object>Set Origin.

Note that this will be a bit more work if your object's origin is not in the center of its geometry. You can still manually place your cursor and choose "Set Origin" "From Cursor".

[image]

Comment: WOW! I also want to add to this post ( since I had this issue come up again ) that the best way to do this I think is to just click on the instanced collection and set the origin point to geometry and then boom... finished :)

Comment: @CameronT0101 I did'nt realize you could do that ! Strangely the "Set Origin" option doesn"t come up when you right click with a collection instance selected, but you can still use the F3 search bar to get it or by the regular menu. I'll update my answer

Comment: Yes, I did forget to mention that I have power snapping pies installed ( Master Xeon 1001 add - on ) so for me it came up and worked instantly. Anyways, this was a very happy mistake and I hope it helps others!