# How do I position my instance empty for collections?

Tags: collections, instances

So today I am working on a huge warehouse scene so I need to be very efficient with my geometry and obviously instancing will be a huge help.

I want to place the empty that represents the collection neatly over the instanced object, but instead that empty wants to be in a totally different location which does not look very clean.

I have tried applying the location, setting it from the world origin, resetting the origin point for the base object and I can't figure it out.

[image]

What I want is in the second image. (keep in mind the second image is just an empty I placed over the lockers to give you a visual for what I am trying to achieve )

Seems like there should be a simple way to place this thing.

[image]

Comment: How to change a collection instance's origin : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164070/86891