# When I add a Collection Instance, I instead get an empty attached to nothing

Tags: instances

This is very simple. I have a cylinder mesh sitting by itself in its own collection. Then I hit SHIFT-A, go down to Collection Instance and select the collection. However, I don't get a collection at my origin point. I instead get an Empty attached to nothing.

I would sure love to know why this is happening. Instancing is so finicky.

Comment: Nope. It's waaaaaaay off the area I'm working in. Somehow, the geometry from the cylindar has become decoupled from its origin point. Even though I fixed the origin point in the source mesh. Hmm...

Comment: You need to change the collection origin. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164070/86891

Comment: Wait. Real solution was that it was actually duplicated. I just didn't realize it. Origin points are still an issue, but it wasn't an empty that was spawned. It was an empty that was accidentally included in the collection that caused me to misunderstand what was happening.