# How can I repeat a mesh using multiple empties with unequal distances?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects

I have a mesh and some empties with unequal distances between them and I want to repeat this mesh and place it where those empties are.

I know that if the distances were equal, I could use an array modifier and object offset. How can I do this for multiple empties with unequal distances?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Collection Instances**

First put your object(s) into their own collection.

Select all your Empties. Go to the *Object* Properties, expand the *Instancing* panel.

Now it is important you keep <kbd>ALT</kbd> pressed until the end. This will propagate the modifications to all selected objects.

Click on *Collection* while still maintaining <kbd>ALT</kbd> and choose the collection you want to instance.

If you want "real" meshes afterwards, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Make Instances Real* or *Object* > *Apply* > *Make Instances real*.

[image]

**Troubleshooting :**

If you don't see any change after these steps:

- Make sure the empties are not in the collection you are trying to instantiate
- The Instanced Collection's origin might be different from what you'd expect. You can tweak it by [following these steps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137523/how-to-change-the-origin-when-moving-a-collection-instance).
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + Click doesn't work because you are emulating a 3 button mouse :

Add a collection instance only for one empty. Select all the other empties too and make sure the instance collection is "active" (yellow outline). Then go to *Object* > *Make Links* > *Instance Collection* or use shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Gaping hole in my understanding of Collection Instances.  I had no idea you could do it this way round. This will save so much time.

Comment: Yup, Adding a collection instance is just a shortcut to manually adding an empty, and then repeating these steps :) mind = blown :D

Comment: .. and you can follow up with Ctrl-A >  _Make Instances Real_, if you want to.

Comment: Wow... That was really good!!! But I have an "issue". If I try it to an empty project, with just a cube, it "works". In my project doesn't!!! Instead of repeat the object, repeats only an empty collection!!! Any idea why is this happening? Please take a look here ( https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Tfv2zMmZ4zab9XhnQiucUidkDA_J4srm?usp=sharing ).

Comment: Make sure your empties are *outside* of the collection you are trying to instance :) The limitation prevents an infinite loop of instancing

Comment: I have already tried that and I still have the same issue!!! :( Is there any case to have to do with any kind of settings etc?

Comment: Maybe share your blend so I can take a look ? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Of course, here it is ( https://pasteall.org/blend/16931f10bcc345b2a736e63ac5cfd5e8 ).

Comment: @Gorgious I think I found it... Mesh should be placed at the center of world and mine wasn't!!! Or should not?

Comment: You identified the problem :) You have two solutions. Either model at world origin or you can offset the collection origin. See my other post on the subject https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137523/how-to-change-the-origin-when-moving-a-collection-instance

Comment: Thank you very much!!! :)

Comment: @Gorgious "Now it is important you keep ALT pressed until the end." It seems that this not work if you have activated "Emulate 3 Button Mouse" in preferences because then it only zooms in/out editor while pressing alt. How this ALT pressing should works if I have that "emulate 3 mouse button" settings activated?

Comment: @SakariNiittymaa Added solution to the answer