# How to move collection without moving the instances?

Tags: collections, instances

I want to move the collection without affecting all the instances since I would have to rearrange the scene. Is there a way to do this?

[image: Collection + Instances]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164070/86891 ?

Comment: Thanks, but that‘s not quite it. The question in the link is about the origins but I want to move the main collection without moving the instances.

Comment: You can move the origin collection, then change its origin, this will reset instances to their starting position