# Collection Instancing: Origin point

Tags: instances, collections

I'm following a kitbash3D tutorial on instancing groups of buildings.

When I make a new collection and instance to scene, the origin point is offset. This is making it difficult to move and rotate the instance properly. It seems impossible to move the origin after instancing.

Is there a way to keep the origin at the centre where it should be?

Comment: You can also try this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164070/86891

Answer (score 1):

You just need to right click on the instance and > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry* (or to 3D cursor). Or open the original collection, move the objects. The instance empty, which will be the instance origin, will be placed where the scene center is relatively to the original objects.