Instance Spawning in Wrong Location
When I create an instance of a model (in this case a chair I want to duplicate many times) and hit ⇧ Shift + A then select Collection Instance... and select the chair instance I have just created it spawns / appears in the wrong place, and I have no idea why.
It doesn't do it for other objects I am instancing, nor does it do it in a fresh project. Only this here project where I really need it.
I've supplied a screen recording to explain the matter is more detail. An image is worth 1000 words and all that. Let me know what you think.
https://youtu.be/mAsybIVEdJo

Hello. Please see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137523/how-to-change-the-origin-when-moving-a-collection-instance

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Why do you use collection instances? Instead use simple instances, just link-duplicate your chair with AltD (instead of ShiftD which will create a copy but with a different mesh).
Note that if you want to replace the existing chairs by the new one, you can select all these old chairs, select the new one and CtrlL > Link Object Data.
As for your problem, if you create a collection instance, the empty that you see and that will be kind of the collection's origin will be created as far from the chair as the chair was far from the center of the world when you've created the collection. If you don't want the chair to be far from the empty, select the original chair and move it close to the world, or even AltG to reset its location.

This is a brilliant answer, thank you very much! Really helpful stuff.
